# NSThread stop / pause

Tags: iphone, nsthread

I have created a NSThread instance in my app. After some point I want to pause it. Is there any way how to do that. I tried doing,

if(![myThread isFinished]) {

myThread = nil;

}

but still i m not able to stop that thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:TIME_TO_PAUSE_THREAD];
```

OR

YOu have to use NSOperation queue for same

Following link may be usefull to you

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ThreadedCoreData/Listings/Classes_ParseOperation_h.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010723-Classes_ParseOperation_h-DontLinkElementID_5

Comment: Thanks nikhil. Actually I thought that sleepForTimeInterval will not work with my thread object. I used your code at some place and it worked.